# what are the advantages of using pipenv sync over pipenv install?

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I am using pipenv to manage my python packages, in my repository, I have both Pipfile and Pipfile.lock versioned. and I want to install all python packages on my live server. should I use `pipenv sync` or `pipenv install`? and why?.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From looking at the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/), it looks like `pipenv install` will install all dependencies from the Pipfile, and update Pipfile.lock with the versions it used.
`pipenv sync` will install the exact versions specified in Pipfile.lock.

I would say `sync` is better for getting your environment to match what is checked in, and `install` is for when you want to get the latest versions, or are adding new dependencies that aren't in the lock file yet.

Comment: Is `sync` better than `install --deploy --ignore-pipfile`?

Comment: They seem about equivalent, functionality-wise, but `sync` feels much clearer, as I had to google what the combination of `--deploy` and `--ignore-pipfile` even did.

Comment: @JeffreyHarmon In this regard then, how is `pipenv install` different from `pipenv update`? Since the docs indicate that the latter also `Runs lock, then sync.`

Comment: @MohammedSafwat I'm not totally sure, but my guess would be that `update` would only update existing packages, whereas `install` would also install ones that are in the pipfile, but not in the environment yet.

Comment: @JeffreyHarmon This way it's becoming increasingly confusing. I think pipenv commands need an overhaul this way.

Comment: I's confusing, I'm coming from Ruby (bundler) world and I'd expect `pipenv install` to install packages exactly as they are specified in Pipfile.lock (ignoring Pipfile), then, `pipenv update` to use Pipfile and update all packages in Pipfile.lock (basically rewrite the lock file with new versions). `pipenv update name` should only update the selected package (name) and its dependencies. Optionally, the 'deployment' flag could save packages to the project directory for easier 'bundling' or uploading to the server.

Comment: I just wanted to add here that if you did `pipenv install --system`, it will not lock `Pipfile.lock`. The message I get it: _Pipfile.lock (c07c41) out of date, but installation uses --system re-building lockfile must happen in isolation. Please rebuild lockfile in a virtualenv. Continuing anyway...
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (c07c41)..._

Comment: And don't forget to use `pipenv sync --dev`, if one of your packages is listed as dev dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation (https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#using-pipenv-for-deployments), sync should be used to install versioned project dependencies. As stated by Jeffrey above, `sync` is a much cleaner approach and will not attempt to modify your lock file.